# Replacing a max pooling layer with an average pooling layer on a VGG model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm following [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576v1) and I try to implement this function:

```
def replace_max_pooling(model):
 '''
 The function replaces max pooling layers with average pooling layers with 
 the following properties: kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0.
 '''
 for layer in model.layers:
    if layer is max pooling:
        replace
```

But I get an error on the iteration that says:

> ModuleAttributeError: 'VGG' object has no attribute 'layers'...

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Have you tried it with [`torch.nn.AvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool2d.html)?

Comment: I have not tried because I'm new to this and don't know how to start... How can I perform the iteration over layers and replacing them?

Answer (score 7):

The VGG model provided by Torchvision contains three components: the `features` sub-module, `avgpool` (the *adaptive average pool*), and the `classifier`. You need to be looking into the head of the network, where the convolution and pool layers are located: `features`.

You can loop over the layers of a `nn.Module` with [`named_children()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_children). However there are other ways of going about this. You can use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to determine if the layer is of a particular type.

In this particular model, layers are named by there index. So in order to locate the appropriate layers in the `nn.Module` and overwrite them, we can convert the names to  *int*s.

```
for i, layer in m.features.named_children():
    if isinstance(layer, torch.nn.MaxPool2d):
        m.features[int(i)] = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
```

---

Having setup beforehand:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
m = models.vgg16()
```